# haproxy keep session after server fail?

Tags: session, load-balancing, haproxy

I have 2 HAProxys that are load balancing user requests with roundrobin algorithm successfully to my 2 WebServers.
When a webserver fails, HAProxy sends the request to the next available server, but for some reason I'm not able to keep the user session, and therefore information isn't displayed properly.
How can I make it so the session is saved during a failover?

Here's my haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client 10000
    timeout server 1000


listen app 192.168.1.100:80
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    stats auth admin:admin
    balance roundrobin
    cookie LSW_WEB insert
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.0
    server server1 192.168.1.93:80 cookie LSW_WEB01 check
    server server2 192.168.1.94:80 cookie LSW_WEB02 check
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how you share sessions between your servers not with haproxy itself.

The problem lies in your application or how you are storing sessions.